# Can`t send information to server using ajax [400 (Bad Request)]

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I can't send `json` object to `Java server` using `ajax`. Browser console throws error:

> GET http: // localhost: 8080 / MySpring / change? {% 22name% 22:% 22d% 22} 400 (Bad Request).

I use `SpringMVC`

---

### HTML file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $("#load").bind("click", function() {
                 var inputText = $("#mytext").val();
                 var task = {name : inputText};
                 $.ajax({
                    url : "change",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    mimeType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(task),
                    success: function (response) {
                        var result = response.name;
                        $("#result_text").text(result);
                    }
                 });    
            });
            
        });
        
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext">
    </br>
    <input type="button" name="load" id="load" value="Load">
    </br>
    <p id="result_text"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
@Controller
public class MailController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/change", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody 
  Task change(@RequestParam String name) {
    Task result = new Task();
    result.setName(name);
    return result;
  }


}
```

Comment: I guess the server does not like the json parameter string. Why don't you use a simple `data: task` instead of the `JSON.stringify`? Or use a POST. Of course this depends on what the server expects.

Comment: A simple `data: task` works. But i need to send JSON object. I wrote such simple object only for example, but in my real project i have more complex JSON object, that contains few parameters.
A `POST` also doesn`t work.

Comment: Can you please add this to your ajax call and see if it gives you the actual error:                                                                                                }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }

Comment: Can you create a chat request and send it. I might be able to help you with this error

Comment: @LearningPhase, it just writes in alert the word "error".

Comment: @VolodymyrObidnyak Let chat about it here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108648/jquery-help

Comment: @LearningPhase I don't have enough reputation for chat :(

Comment: @VolodymyrObidnyak Lets start from the basics

Comment: @VolodymyrObidnyak You request is not even reaching your controller, correct?

Comment: @LearningPhase Yes, it is correct

Comment: Adding it as an answer as it makes formatting easy

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also instead of dynamically adding json just hard code the it like {"name":"test"}

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "HERE PUT THE PATH OF YOUR SERVICE OR PAGE",
            data: '{"HERE YOU CAN PUT DATA TO PASS AT THE SERVICE"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
               //do something
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {

                //do something else

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem with the controller mapping.
Your controller is expecting:

```
http://localhost:8080/MySpring/change?name=yourData
```

but you are calling

```
http://localhost:8080/MySpring/change?yourData
```

Consider also changing method from GET to POST according to http get length limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#load").bind("click", function() {
                     var inputText = $("#mytext").val();
                     var task = {name : inputText};
                     $.ajax({
                        url : "change",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        mimeType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(task),
                        traditional : true,
                        success: function (response) {
                            var result = response.name;
                            $("#result_text").text(result);
                        }
                     });    
                });
            });
    </script>


Added traditional : true, in Ajax call
```